# Haskell: get list of strings from file

Tags: haskell

My input is:

```
Plaster ["BD..", ".GA.D", ".FEG", "ABDCF", "E..."]
```

What I'm trying to get:

`["BD..", ".GA.D", ".FEG", "ABDCF", "E..."]`

My code for now:

```
go = do --print "Enter file name"
        --path <- getLine
        file <- (readFile "1.txt")
        print file
        let list = consume file 
        print list
        let content = (wordsWhen (=='"') list) 
        print content
        print (content !! 0)
        print (content !! 1)
        print (content !! 2)


wordsWhen :: (Char -> Bool) -> String -> [String]
wordsWhen p s =  case dropWhile p s of
                      "" -> []
                      ", " -> []
                      s' -> w : wordsWhen p s''
                            where (w, s'') = break p s'

consume []       = []
consume ('[':xs) = consume' xs
consume (_  :xs) = consume xs

consume' []       = [] 
consume' (']':xs) = []
consume' (x  :xs) = x : consume' xs
```

So what I'm doing is

- Read file from destination (now hardcoded for testing)
- Get rid of the word "Plaster" with `consume`
- Get all strings from file with `wordsWhen`

I tried different separators for `wordsWhen`, but I can't get what I need. In current form the output is:

```
"Plaster [\"BD..\", \".GA.D\", \".FEG\", \"ABDCF\", \"E...\"]"
"\"BD..\", \".GA.D\", \".FEG\", \"ABDCF\", \"E...\""
["BD..",", ",".GA.D",", ",".FEG",", ","ABDCF",", ","E..."]
"BD.."
", "
".GA.D"
```

Which is quite accurate, but I want to get rid of this words that contains only commas. I can change the separator to comma (which it's supposed to be, I think), but then output is given with all this slashes and quotation marks, like this:

```
"Plaster [\"BD..\", \".GA.D\", \".FEG\", \"ABDCF\", \"E...\"]"
"\"BD..\", \".GA.D\", \".FEG\", \"ABDCF\", \"E...\""
["\"BD..\""," \".GA.D\""," \".FEG\""," \"ABDCF\""," \"E...\""]
"\"BD..\""
" \".GA.D\""
" \".FEG\""
```

Is there a way to fix my code? Or should I do it in a different way?

EDIT: As it is my exercise, I can only use standard types and functions.

Comment: Is this for you to exercise, if not maybe you can use Parsec https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec

Comment: Yes, it is my exercise, so unfortunately I can't use it.

Comment: Maybe you can still use it for inspiration, like for example build some small parser and then combine them.

Comment: Well, as a beginner I must admit that I have no idea how to do it, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could cheat by defining a datatype with a `Read` instance that matches your existing input:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall -Werror -Wno-name-shadowing #-}
module Main where

data Input = Plaster [String] deriving (Read, Show)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  Plaster xs <- readIO =<< readFile "1.txt"
  _ <- traverse print (zip [0 :: Int ..] xs)
  return ()
```

This works perfectly for me with ghc-8.0.2:

```
$ cat "1.txt"
Plaster ["BD..", ".GA.D", ".FEG", "ABDCF", "E..."]
$ ghc --make SO44269043.hs && ./SO44269043
(0,"BD..")
(1,".GA.D")
(2,".FEG")
(3,"ABDCF")
(4,"E...")
```

---

Alternately, you could define your own read instance:

```
data Input = Plaster [String]

instance Read Input where
  readsPrec p = readParen (p >= 10) . runR $ do
    Plaster <$> (string "Plaster" *> many1 whitespace *> R readList)
```

If you're unfamiliar with `<$>` and `*>`, it may be a little easier to read this as

```
  readsPrec p = readParen (p >= 10) . runR $ do
    _ <- string "Plaster"
    _ <- many1 whitespace
    xs <- R readList
    return (Plaster xs)
```

Even without imports, it's not a lot of code to define a parser type `R`, basically just a wrapper that lets you define a monad instance for `String -> [(a, String)]`:

```
newtype R a = R { runR :: ReadS a }

instance Functor R where
  fmap f = R . fmap (map (\(a, s) -> (f a, s))) . runR

instance Applicative R where
  pure a = R $ \s -> [(a, s)]
  mf <*> ma = R $ \s -> do
    (f, s) <- runR mf s
    (a, s) <- runR ma s
    return (f a, s)

instance Monad R where
  m >>= f = R $ \s -> do
    (a, s) <- runR m s
    runR (f a) s
```

The `>>=` (or bind) operator just means "parse some of the string
with the parser on the left, then parse the rest of the string
with the after passing the resulting value to the function on the right."

We get `R readList :: R [String]` for free now, so all we need to do
is skip the initial "Plaster" and any whitespace between that and the 
list of strings:

```
string :: String -> R String
string = traverse char

many1 :: R a -> R [a]
many1 r = loop where
  loop = (:) <$> r <*> (loop <|> return [])

whitespace :: R Char
whitespace = char ' ' <|> char '\t' <|> char '\n' <|> char '\r'
```

Normally we'd use `<|>` from `GHC.Base`, but it's not hard to define a one-off here. Basically
`r <|> r'` means "try to parse with `r`, and if it fails, try to parse with `r'` instead"

```
(<|>) :: R a -> R a -> R a
r <|> r' = R $ \s -> runR r s ++ runR r' s
```

And now all we need is the ability to match a single character:

```
char :: Char -> R Char
char c = R $ \s -> case s of
  (c' : s) | c == c'  -> [(c, s)]
  _                   -> []
```

---

If even using `Prelude.readList` is too easy, we can define our own parsers for lists and quoted strings:

```
  readsPrec p = readParen (p >= 10) . runR $ do
    Plaster <$> (string "Plaster" *> many1 whitespace *> listOf quotedString)
```

Where lists just have a leading '[', a trailing ']', and some number of delimited terms:

```
listOf :: R a -> R [a]
listOf term = char '[' *> (term `sepBy` string ", ") <* char ']'

sepBy :: R a -> R b -> R [a]
sepBy term delim = sepBy1 term delim <|> return []

sepBy1 :: R a -> R b -> R [a]
sepBy1 term delim = loop where
  loop = (:) <$> term <*> ((delim *> loop) <|> return [])
```

Similarly, a quoted string just has a leading '"', a trailing '"', and some number of escaped characters:

```
quotedString :: R String
quotedString = char '"' *> many escapedChar <* char '"'

many :: R a -> R [a]
many r = many1 r <|> return []

escapedChar :: R Char
escapedChar = R $ \s -> case s of
  '\\' : '\\' : s               -> [('\\', s)]
  '\\' : '"' : s                -> [('"', s)]
  c : s | c /= '\\' && c /= '"' -> [(c, s)]
  _                             -> []
```

---

It's worth noting the similarity between `many/many1` and `sepBy/sepBy1` - if we were really
lazy, we could define one in terms of the other:

```
many1 r = r `sepBy1` return ()
term `sepBy1` delim = (:) <$> term <*> many (delim *> term)
```

Comment: Actually I think I can use `Read` instance, so that would be it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can use it only if you implement it yourself. Deriving `Read` might be "too easy".

Comment: This answer inspired me to learn Haskell even more. You solution is very "functional".

Answer (score 2):

This is how it could be done:

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Data.Maybe
import Text.Read

readStringList :: String -> Maybe [String]
readStringList = readMaybe

main = do --print "Enter file name"
        handle <- openFile "1.txt" ReadMode
        hSeek handle AbsoluteSeek 8 
        file <- hGetContents handle
        let list = fromJust (readStringList file )
        print list
        let filterThis = "," :: String
        let filtered = filter (/=filterThis) list
        print filtered
```

To get first command line argument, use `getArgs`.

Comment: If it's for an exercise, I'd think that using a `Read` instance is a bit cheating.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, but I'm afraid I can't use `System.Environment` nor `Text.Read`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty parser.
Be careful, it only works for well formed input, is not performant and code is not factorised. But there is no cheating ;)
Maybe it could give you some inspiration to solve your exercise.

```
plaster :: String -> String
plaster ('P':'l':'a':'s':'t':'e':'r':' ':xs) = xs
plaster s = undefined


brackets :: String -> String
brackets ('[':xs) = brackets xs
brackets (x:']':_) = [x]
brackets (x:xs) = x:brackets xs


quotes :: String -> String
quotes ('"':xs) = quotes xs
quotes (x:'"':_) = [x]
quotes (x:xs) = x:quotes xs


sepByComma :: String -> [String]
sepByComma s = go s ""
  where
    go [] acc = [acc] 
    go (',':' ':xs) acc  = [acc] ++ go xs ""
    go (x:xs) acc = go xs (acc ++ [x])


parse :: String -> [String]
parse s = map quotes . sepByComma . brackets . plaster $ s
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using only the very basics, no `Monads`, `Functors` or `Applicative` operators.

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  input <- getLine
  let output = parse input
  print output

parse :: String -> [String]
parse = map stripQuotes . parse' . tokenize []
  where
    parse' :: [String] -> [String]
    -- If the input matches the pattern, call parseList on the inner tokens.
    -- Does not nest brackets!  This is a simple regex match.
    parse' ("Plaster":"[":tokens) | last tokens == "]" =
      parseList [] (removeLast tokens)
    parse' _ = error "The input does not have the form \"Plaster [...]\"."

parseList :: [String] -> [String] -> [String]
-- Empty list.
parseList tokens [] = tokens
-- Unexpected tokens.
parseList _ (",":_) = error "Unexpected comma."
parseList _ ("[":_) = error "No support for nested brackets."
parseList _ ("]":_) = error "Unexpected input after \"]\"."
-- One-element list.
parseList tokens [x] = tokens ++ [x]
-- Comma-separated list with at least two elements.
parseList tokens (x:",":y:ys) = parseList (tokens ++ [x]) (y:ys)
-- Comma at end of list, so we don’t want to give the "expected comma" error!
parseList _ [_,","] = error "Extra comma at end of list."
-- More than one element not separated by commas.
parseList _ (x:_) = error $ "Expected comma after \"" ++ x ++ "\"."

stripQuotes :: String -> String
stripQuotes ('"':xs) | last xs == '"' = removeLast xs
stripQuotes xs = error $ "Expected string literal instead of " ++ xs ++ "."

removeLast :: [a] -> [a]
removeLast xs = take ((length xs) - 1) xs

whitespace :: [Char]
whitespace = [' ', '\n', '\t'] -- Incomplete, but sufficient.

isWhitespace :: Char -> Bool
isWhitespace c = elem c whitespace

tokenize :: [String] -> String -> [String]
-- If we’ve consumed all the input, we’re done.
tokenize tokens [] = tokens
-- We’d need something a little more complicated for longer operators:
tokenize tokens ('[':xs) = tokenize (tokens ++ ["["]) xs
tokenize tokens (']':xs) = tokenize (tokens ++ ["]"]) xs
tokenize tokens (',':xs) = tokenize (tokens ++ [","]) xs
-- Not currently processing a token, so skip whitespace.
-- Otherwise, start a new token.
tokenize tokens (x:xs) | isWhitespace x = tokenize tokens xs
                       | otherwise      = tokenize' tokens [x] xs
  where
    tokenize' :: [String] -> String -> String -> [String]
-- If we’ve consumed all the input, the current token is the last.
    tokenize' ts t [] = ts ++ [t]
-- If we encounter an operator, it is the token after the current one.
    tokenize' ts t ('[':ys) = tokenize (ts ++ [t] ++ ["["]) ys
    tokenize' ts t (']':ys) = tokenize (ts ++ [t] ++ ["]"]) ys
    tokenize' ts t (',':ys) = tokenize (ts ++ [t] ++ [","]) ys
-- Whitespace means the current token is complete.
-- Otherwise, append y to the current token and continue.
    tokenize' ts t (y:ys) | isWhitespace y = tokenize (ts ++ [t]) ys
                          | otherwise      = tokenize' ts (t ++ [y]) ys
```

You wouldn’t do this in production code; this is simple enough to do with a regex, and parsing is (more or less) a solved problem.  Parser combinators are the trendy way to go.